# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SessionFactory when I try to deploy the war

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, tomcat

I am trying to deploy war on TC server using STS. I am able to build the project without any dependency issues. But once I try to add the war to the server , I get the following error:

```
[2017-03-29 09:27:14,303] ERROR [ContextLoader]Context initialization failed 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ApplConfigService': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configManager': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'UserAuthentication': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: SessionFactory
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:586)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1750)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Troubleshooting steps I tried:

1. I made sure the war that was built had all the necessary jars under WEB_INF/lib
2. Tried adding the jars to buildpath
3. Made sure maven dependencies are added under Preferences->Deployment Assembly
4. Cleaned the server several times
5. Forced maven to download all the jars again
6. Did Maven install from command line to make sure the wars are building properly
7. Tried deploying the war manually into tomcat/STS and starting the server on command line. It starts without this error but gives 404 for the application URL.
8. Tried STS and Eclipse

   For some reason it is not able to find the Hibernate jars from the server. I have tried most of the solutions I came across for this error on Stack overflow but it doesn't go away.

Any insights on this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's odd that the `NoClassDefFoundError` mentions only `SessionFactory` rather than `org.hibernate.SessionFactory`.  How is the session factory configured in your app?

Comment: Thank you for your response! Looks like it was the problem with the IDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with IDE. I copied the WEB-INF folder from target folder of the project and pasted it the folder in server path overriding the WEB-INF present there:

[Server path location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncb6w.png)

I am able to start the server now with no issues

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, this would be better as a comment.  But for posterity sake: Many people are not aware that a war file and an ear file are simply zipped up content with specific files in specific places.  To look at the file, you can rename the extension to ".zip" and then browse the files inside.

I know you already answered your own question, but others might find this useful. :)